# RG flow diagram plotting

Tags: renormalization, non-linear-systems

I want to be able to plot a flow diagram with a given recursion relation.

For example, I have the follow recursion relation:

\begin{align*}
    \frac{dT}{d\ell} &= 2T{y_0}^2 a^2
    \\
    \frac{d y_0}{d\ell}
    &= \frac{T-2}{T} y_0
\end{align*}

(If it matters...)

I couldn't find any straight-forward way to plot its' flow diagram via Python or Mathematica. Is there any comfortable way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with RG, but if this is simply the flow of a vector field you could try matplotlib's streamplot() function in python.

Comment: I familiar with streamplot(), unfortunately, I found it helpless without solving explicitly the recursion relations.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if these recursion relations (being a system of nonlinear ODEs) have an explicit solution. It is however fairly simple to discretize $l$ and try for example an Euler scheme
$$
T_i=T_{i-1}+\dot T(T_{i-1},y_{i-1})\,\Delta l\,,~~y_i=y_{i-1}+\dot y(T_{i-1},y_{i-1})\,\Delta l\,,~~\mbox{(Euler)}
$$
where $\dot T,\dot y$ are the functions given by your $dT/dl$ and $dy/dl\,.$ I tried two slightly different schemes so measure the impact on the solution. As we know, non linear equations are numerically not very stable:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&T_i=T_{i-1}+\dot T(T_{i-1},y_{i-1})\,\Delta l\,,~~y_i=y_{i-1}+\dot y(T_i,y_{i-1})\,\Delta l\,,~~\mbox{(semi~explicit I)}\\
&&T_i=T_{i-1}+\dot T(T_{i-1},y_i)\,\Delta l\,,~~y_i=y_{i-1}+\dot y(T_{i-1},y_{i-1})\,\Delta l\,.~~\mbox{(semi~explicit II)}
\end{eqnarray*}
To test the quality of these very simple schemes (and others) further you can looke at the case of large $T$ where the system becomes linear and can easily be solved:
$$
y(l)=y(0)e^l\,,~~T(l)=T(0)\exp(a^2y^2(0)(e^{2l}-1))\,.\mbox{(large-$T$-Approx)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Mathematica `NDSolve` works. You have to follow up the output of `NDsolve` with with some extra stuff in order to plot.  Here is an example of solving a three-d set of nonlinear flow equations:

```
c = NDSolve[{s'[x] ==  k[x] u[x]/2, 
    u'[x] == k[x] (1 + 2 s[x]) - 2 Omega[x]  t[x], 
    t'[x] == 2 Omega [x]  u[x], 
    s[0] == u[0] == t[0] == 0}, {s, t, u}, {x, 0, 500}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 24]
```

This outputs an "interpolating function" and plotting `t` and `u`, for example, requires

```
Plot[{Evaluate[ t[x] /. c], Evaluate[ u[x] /. c]}, {x, 200, 500}, 
    PlotRange -> Full ]
```

The  `/.c`, meaning  `ReplaceAll`  is  an instruction to replace the `ToRules` output of `NdSolveo`  by the  actual interpolating functions.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your attention.

1. You haven't specified `Omega[t]` and `k[t]` in the code you attached. (I just ignored them)

2. The plot itself is not the RG flow (the `s`-`t`-`u` flow space) but the way that each one of them scales with `t`.

I was aiming for something like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/306474516/figure/fig11/AS:669063890100243@1536528670729/Another-example-of-RG-flow-with-L-I-and-CH-S-0-that-has-one-sink-one-source-and.png).

Comment: Omega[t] and k[t] are some given functions. I was solving equation such as those in eq 68 in arXiv:2301.07059. Your RG flows are similar  first-order ODE's.